# I am using depreciated code for ViewPager. I want to update it but can only find fragment tutorials

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using layouts in the ViewPager because I don't have a need for fragments.  How do I implement a ViewPager with layouts?  I am using pagerslidingtabstrip library but I don't believe that should be an issue.  If you need any more code or questions I can update my question.  I removed most of the layout to make it simple.

Here is my old code.

```
 instantiateItem() is depreciated.
```

**Adapter**

```
class HomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.id.home_layout;
                return "Projects";
            case 1:
                resId = R.id.home_projects;
                return "Schedule";
        }
        return getPageTitle(position);
    }

    /*
     Depreciated, need to find out what is going to be replacing the depreciated statement
    */
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.id.home_layout;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.id.home_projects;
                break;
        }
        return findViewById(resId);
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == (arg1);
    }
}
```

**ViewPager Implementaton**

```
ViewPager pager;
HomePagerAdapter pgAdapter;
PagerSlidingTabStrip homePTS;

private void viewPager() {
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pgAdapter = new HomePagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(pgAdapter);
    homePTS = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    homePTS.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

**Layout**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/home_layout">

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/home_projects">

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**Updated**

```
    // Changed View to ViewGroup.  It Worked but not sure if it the proper way to do it?
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGoup collection, int position) {

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.id.home_layout;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.id.home_projects;
                break;
        }
        return findViewById(resId);
    }
```

Comment: Updated question.  Posted the depreciated part of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond overriding a deprecated method, `instantiateItem()` is supposed to *instantiate* an item. That's why the word "instantiate" is in the method name. You are not instantiating an item, but instead are trying to use an existing widget owned by something else, which breaks the `PagerAdapter` contract and is unlikely to be reliable over time.

So, your `instantiateItem()` method should either use `LayoutInflater` (via `getLayoutInflater()` on your `Activity`) to `inflate()` a layout, or construct the appropriate UI for the page in Java code. It needs to add that new UI as a child `View` of the `ViewGroup` passed into the non-deprecated version of `instantiateItem()`.

For example, here is an activity that has a `ViewPager` with a `View`-based `PagerAdapter`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.mvp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private ViewPager pager=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter());
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
  }

  /*
   * Inspired by
   * https://gist.github.com/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1
   */
  private class SampleAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      View page=
          getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);
      TextView tv=(TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.text);
      int blue=position * 25;

      final String msg=
          String.format(getString(R.string.item), position + 1);

      tv.setText(msg);
      tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
               .show();
        }
      });

      page.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, blue));
      container.addView(page);

      return(page);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
                            Object object) {
      container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return(9);
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
      return(0.5f);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return(view == object);
    }
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1))

In `instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)`, I inflate a layout, customize the contents, and add the `View` manually to the `container`. In truth, I could probably pass `true` as the third parameter to the `inflate()` method and skip the extra `addView()` call, though I have not tried that.

Comment: I have went through this code already and I still dont understand how to inflate a layout for each view.  Can you try and explain that to me?

Comment: @EugeneH: Call `getLayoutInflater()` on your `Activity` to get a `LayoutInflater`. Call `inflate()` on the `LayoutInflater` to inflate the layout.

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying.   I am going to try something out. I will get back to you.

Comment: I am trying to get things moving but its not working.  Would you be able to update your answer with inflating two layouts?

Comment: @EugeneH: Um, that's just an `if` statement. If nothing else, create two versions of `instantiateItem()` (`instantiateItemOne()` and `instantiateItemTwo()`) and have `instantiateItem()` delegate to the desired implementation.

Comment: I ended up changing the view to ViewGroup.  I updated the question.  It works but is it the proper way to implement it?

Comment: @EugeneH: `ViewPager` expects `PagerAdapter` to create ("instantiate") the pages. I would not expect your approach to be reliable over time.